# Command binding not working in WPF with prism

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, prism

Event Binding in WPF MVVM Pattern with Prism Library isn't working for the buttons in child user control.

I have a base view `PreparationMockView`, in which I have a content control, which is a child view `LeftBarPrepMockView`. Now when clicking on a button in `LeftBarPrepMockView`, `SelectedTaskCommand` isn't triggered.

Below are the parent and child views and the respective view model.

- Parent View:

  ```
   <UserControl x:Class="PreparationMockUp.Views.PreparationMockView"
               xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
               xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
               xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
               xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
               xmlns:mvvm="http://prismlibrary.com/"
               xmlns:preparationMockUp="clr-namespace:PreparationMockUp"
               mvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
               mc:Ignorable="d">
       <Grid>
           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
               <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" mvvm:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static preparationMockUp:PreparationMockUpModule.LeftBarPreparationRegionName}" />
           <TabControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" TabStripPlacement ="Left" Background="#f2f2f3">
       <Grid>
   <UserControl>
  ```
- Child View:

  ```
   <UserControl x:Class="PreparationMockUp.Views.LeftBarPrepMockView"
               xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
               xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
               xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
               xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
               xmlns:mvvm="http://prismlibrary.com/"
               mvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
               mc:Ignorable="d">
           <Grid Background="#1a2231">
           <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
               <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
           </Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
           <!-- Bind Rows using the default StackPanel for the ItemsPanel -->
               <ItemsControl Name="taskDisplayList" ItemsSource="{Binding TaskList, Mode=TwoWay}">
               <!-- Set the Template for each row to a TextBlock and another ItemsControl -->
                   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                           <Grid Margin="5">
                               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                   <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                                   <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                   <Button Name="SelectTaskButton" Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding SelectedTaskCommand}" 
                                       CommandParameter="{Binding}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode= TwoWay}" 
                                       BorderThickness ="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                       Style="{StaticResource TaskButton}"
                                       Content="{Binding Name}">
                               </Button>
                           </Grid>
                   </DataTemplate>
               </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
           </ItemsControl>
           </StackPanel>
       </Grid>
   <UserControl>
  ```
- Viewmodel:

  ```
   namespace PreparationMockUp.ViewModels
   {
       public class LeftBarPrepMockViewModel : ViewModelBase
       {
           private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
           private Tasks tasks;
           readonly string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConfigPath"].ToString();

           public LeftBarPrepMockViewModel(IEventAggregator ea)
           {
               _eventAggregator = ea;
               _eventAggregator.GetEvent<PubSubEvent<PubSubMessages>>().Subscribe((message) => InsertedCylinder(),
                   ThreadOption.UIThread, true, x => x.Equals(PubSubMessages.InsertedBuildCylinder));
               SelectedTaskCommand = new DelegateCommand(NavigateToSelectedTask);
           }

           public ICommand SelectedTaskCommand { get; set; }

           private List<Task> _taskList;
           public List<Task> TaskList 
           { 
               get 
               {
                   return _taskList;
               }
               set
               {
                   _taskList = value;
                   OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TaskList"));
               } 
           }
           private void NavigateToSelectedTask(){ }           
       }
   }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You bind the `SelectedTaskCommand` to an element named `root`, but it does not exist in your code.

```
Command="{Binding SelectedTaskCommand, ElementName=root}"
```

Let's assume you meant the `ItemsControl` named `taskDisplayList`. Then you could create a binding using [`ElementName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.elementname?view=net-5.0), but you would still need to refer to the `DataContext` of that element in order to bind to the view model. Otherwise the binding will search for a property on the control itself, which does not exist.

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectedTaskCommand, ElementName=taskDisplayList}"
```

An alternative is to use a [`RelativeSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Data.Binding.RelativeSource);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-5.0) binding the `LeftBarPrepMockView` user control.

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectedTaskCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:LeftBarPrepMockView}}}"
```

You can of course use bind to the `ItemsControl` or other controls, too, without [`ElementName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.elementname?view=net-5.0).

Comment: @RamakrishnaReddy Are there any binding errors in your output window?